# Condição no MySQL em consulta de dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Há alguma maneira de fazer uma condição para demostrar dados apenas se o `status` esteja como `aprovado` no banco de dados?

**MySQL:**

```
Nome  ProdValor   Data         Status
Goku  250,00      15/04/2015   Aprovado
Goku  250,00      15/04/2015   Pendente
Goku  250,00      15/04/2015   Cancelado
```

**PHP**

```
 $busca = mysql_connect("$local","$usuario","$senha") or die("ERRO AO CONECTAR AO MYSQL, VERIFIQUE COM O ADMINISTRADOR" . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("$banco") or die("BASE DE DADOS INVÁLIDO");
 $pesquisa = mysql_query("SELECT sum(ProdValor) FROM vendas WHERE MONTH(data) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH))");

  while($sum = mysql_fetch_array($pesquisa)){
      $soma2 = $sum['sum(ProdValor)'];
  }    

  echo $soma2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Seria algo assim:

```
SELECT SUM(ProdValor) FROM vendas
    WHERE MONTH(data) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) AND Status = 'Aprovado'
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/PreviousMonth.sql).

Como você não deu muitos detalhes, pode ser necessário alguma adaptação ao que você vai fazer. O ideal é que a coluna de `Status` não fosse texto.

Comment: Testei o seu exemplo e funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado. O campo que estou utilizando é varchar.

Comment: Já marquei como mais correta, obrigado.